# Font Scaling and maxFontSizeMultiplier on Alerts

Tags: react-native, alert

I am trying to set maxFontSizeMultiplier on the react native Alert component, but I cannot find any way to do it. I don't want to make another component just for Alerts.

I am using the following code:

```
Alert.alert('Alert', 'My Message', alertActions, options);
```

Is there any way to disable font scaling or specify maxFontSizeMultiplier for Alerts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom library  [react-native-modalbox](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox).

You'll be able to style the modal:

```
        <Modal style={{background: 'red'}} ref={"modal"}>
          <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>your alert</Text>
          <Button onPress={this.toggleSwipeToClose} style={styles.btn}>Close({this.state.swipeToClose ? "true" : "false"})</Button>
        </Modal>
```

You can open the modal using

```
openModal(id) {
    this.refs.modal.open();
  }
```

[more options](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox/blob/master/Example/index.ios.js) .

Comment: So currently there is no way to handle this using just the native Alert component provided by react-native correct?